# How to remove a class from a post_image div?

Tags: post-class

So for a post i know how to remove a class by using

```
function remove_class( $classes ) {
            $classes = array_diff($classes, array('hentry'));   
        return $classes;
}

add_filter('post_class', 'remove_class');
```

But i need to remove a particular class from a child div of the post div, i.e. a div with class="post_image mb30 blur icon" and i like to remove blur.

It turns out the WP theme in use, adds the class by:

```
    function content_thumbnail_masonry($args = array()) {
 global $post; 
$args['width'] = '768'; 
$args['height'] = ''; 
$args['crop'] = false; 
$args['class'] = 'post_image mb15'; 
if (get_post_format() == 'quote') { 
$args['show'] = false; 
} elseif (get_post_format() == 'link') {
 $args['show'] = false; 
} 
return $args; }
```

I also tried this:

```
function remove_css_please( $content ) {
    global $post; 
    $postid = $post->ID;
    if( $postid==5709) {
    echo 'yes for this one';
    $content = str_replace('<div class="post_image mb30 blur icon">','<div class="post_image mb30">', $content);
    } 
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_css_please');
```

But the preg_replace doesn't work, the echo did show up.

i like to remove the a href tag as well

Comment: How is `post_image` added in the first place? It looks like you may have two separate questions in one.

Comment: @s_ha_dum that's a good one. I was given a theme to use, but i guess the post_image is added because of the post format is set to image. And post format is a general WP 3.8 feature.

Comment: I did a quick `grep` for that class and didn't find it. Perhaps it is dynamically generated, but it may also be part of the theme. I am not sure, and without knowing I don't think I can help.

Comment: @s_ha_dum you are correct post_image is not a native WP class. I think `function content_thumbnail_masonry($args = array()) {
 global $post;
 
 $args['width'] = '768';
 $args['height'] = '';
 $args['crop'] = false;
 $args['class'] = 'post_image mb15';
 
 if (get_post_format() == 'quote') {
  $args['show'] = false;
 } elseif (get_post_format() == 'link') {
  $args['show'] = false;
 }
 return $args;
}`
As i don't like to alter the theme files so i am trying to create a function in functions.php which removes the class by `add_filter('the_content', 'remove_class_please');`

Comment: [Edit] that code into the question as well as the code where that function is used. Is it hooked in somewhere?